# REST web service to recover an array of pictures

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, arrays

I want to implement a web service to recover an array of my entity PictureCaptures :

```
PictureCaptures
---------------
- description : string
- captureDate : DateTime
- photoBinary : byte[]
```

The web service will be mainly called by an `iOS` application.

What's the best way to implement it, because of the byte array attribute?

Am I suppose to return the byte array without any transformation, as a simple `JSON` attribute? If yes, how to interpet the `JSON` response ? -In this case `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` doesn't work, too much data and memory issue)-

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

when you get JSON responce you shoud convert the btye array to NSData.
first add Base64.h and m file to the project ( you can find it easily on internet)

then import Base64.h

from your JSON data

```
NSString *data= [yourJSONDict objectForKey:@"photoBinary"];
          NSData* imageData = [data base64DecodedData];

        UIImage *imag=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [yourImageView setImage:imag];
```

this might help you.

Comment: Yes but to recover a JSONDict I need to use the JSONObjectWithData:options:error method, and this make me a memory issue because I have a lot of picture in the data response.

Comment: if you post some code or what issue exaclty you get then someone can dafinately help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add two resources: one for the meta data (description, captureDate and so on) and one for the binary data. Let the meta data resource contain a link to the binary photo data.

Like this:

```
GET /images/1234
```

Response:

```
{
  description: "Nice photo",
  captureDate: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
  photoData: "http://example.org/images/1234/photo"
}
```

and http://example.org/images/1234/photo returns the raw photo data

(see also See also [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) for a discussion on date formats).